# How can I handle various errors to prevent app from crash?

Tags: javascript, angular

I saw a few solutions for error handling.

The main idea is behind this explanation: https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler

I tried to implement it to catch TypeError but it doesn't work:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorsHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(
     private injector: Injector,
  ) { }

  handleError(error: Error | HttpErrorResponse | TypeError) {
    const notificationService = this.injector.get(NotificationService);
    const dataService = this.injector.get(DataService);
    const router = this.injector.get(Router);

    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {    
        if (!navigator.onLine) {
            // No Internet connection
            return notificationService.notify('No Internet Connection');
        }
        // Http Error
        // Send the error to the server
        console.log(error);
        // Show notification to the user
        return notificationService.notify(`${error.status} - ${error.message}`);
    } else if (error instanceof TypeError) {
        console.log('This is TypeError!', error);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In elseif block check for this

```
err instanceof Error || err instanceof TypeError
```